# Dual monitors using DisplayPort "disconnect" and "reconnect" when waking from sleep

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, sleep, nvidia-graphics-card, lg-monitor

Brand new video card (4070 Ti) and brand new monitors (both LG Ultragear 27GP83-B) connected via DisplayPort.

When the screens go to sleep and I shake them awake with my mouse, I first hear the Windows "disconnected device" sound, then a new "connected device" sound and each monitor refreshes black->screen->black->screen->black->screen. It takes at least 10 seconds for that to happen before I can use my computer.

To top it all off, all of my windows get moved over to the display set as Primary.

Previously, I had two Samsung displays attached via HDMI to an RX 580 on the same motherboard, hardware, install of Windows 10, etc. and it had zero issues.

Is it something about DisplayPort? The GPU? Windows? It's incredibly annoying.

Comment: The displays aren't waking 'fast enough'. If you can manually wake them before the computer, try that. It's a common issue with no real fix a lot of the time.

Comment: @Tetsujin Interesting! How does one manually wake a monitor other than to move the mouse?

Comment: Depends on the model. Often just tapping one of the front panel buttons [not the on/of] will do it. [well, the on/off would probably also do it, but you'd have to wait much longer for it to cycle.]

Comment: @Tetsujin I believe there is only a nub, but I could try rocking it. I'll report back.